# Find next word with desired color using pyqt TextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to make a "search for color" button in my pyqt application. I've been searching the documentation but I couldn't come up with a solution better than this:

```
cursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()
format = cursor.charFormat()
while ((format.foreground().color() == QtCore.Qt.black) and (not cursor.atEnd())):
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextWord);
    format = cursor.charFormat()
```

It seems so ugly and slow. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "seems"? Have you actually timed it and found there to be a significant performance issue?

Comment: No, but thought maybe there was a better way, some regex magic or something for formatted text. I guess sweeping the text char by char will be the way then, thanks